# How to access EF Core InMemory DB from SpecFlow test?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, specflow, in-memory-database

My setup is this:

1. I have a REST API written in .NET Core using Web API. It is fetching data from a SQL Server database using Entity Framework. It is setup so it wil use an Entity Framework In-Memory DB if the environment is "Test".
2. I've created a SpecFlow test project in .NET Framework (as SpecFlow doesn't support .NET core yet).

**My question is this:**

*How do I inject data in the API In-Memory DB from the SpecFlow Steps? Does the In-Memory DB have a Connection String that I can use to insert data, or is there some other way to do it?*

I have the following Scenario (simplified):

```
Given the user 'JohnDoe' with rating '123' is exists
When I request the API with HTTP GET '/users/JohnDoe/rating'
Then I get the rating '123'
```

In the Given step I would like to put the user in the In-Memory DB so the API can find it and return it.

Comment: You won't be able to insert data in an in-memory database running in a different process. You could, of course, implement an endpoint to insert such data, but you run the risk of accidentally exposing test-only endpoints in production code that way, it's more ways for the test to fail, and it's also more scaffolding. Consider making the code under test part of a .NET Standard library, as you will be able to use that in a SpecFlow runner on .NET Framework. Alternatively, consider using an actual SQL LocalDB instance to run the tests against, though that will slow things down a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Jeroen. My API already have CRUD commands for the things I want to test, so I think I'll just use the API to get the data in the database. Notthe preferred way to do it, but it will get the job done.

I used to work with RavenDB and it has a nice InMemory DB that is accessable from "the outside". I was hoping the EF In-Memory DB would do the same thing, but I guess not.